# Restrict Menu Item Visibility by Permissions

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a module-generated menu (using yaml file) with 5 menu items. My requirements don't allow me to restrict menu item visibility by role because roles can be dynamically added. So I have to do this using permissions only.

**What I've tried**
(1) Restricting menu item access using route permissions - this shows a page forbidden but still allows the restricted menu item to be visible

Please see my actual files below:

**portal_hrm_core.links.menu.yml**

```
portal_hrm_core.hrm_link:
  title: 'HR Manager'
  route_name: portal_hrm_core.hrm_link
  menu_name: hcm
  expanded: TRUE
```

**portal_hrm_core.routing.yml**

```
portal_hrm_core. hrm_link:
path: '/admin/hrm' 
defaults:
  _controller: '\Drupal... systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
  _title: 'HRM'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access hrm_core_job+access_hrm_core_employee'
```

(2) Contrib modules - `Menu Item Visibility` and `Menu Item Per Role`
Both of these are only role-based and can't support permissions

I know I can go really low-level and use something like `hook_preprocess_menu` but seems to heavy for such a simple requirement considering how many times that hook may be called.

So folks, please any further suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK point (1) is correct and should also hide menu items (using that method in my own projects). Menus are heavily cached, have you cleared cache after adding route permissions?

Comment: Hudri - your quick reply has strongly encouraged me! Thanks. Please I've updated the original question with my source files for your review. And I cleared the cache using both ```devel menu ui``` and ```drush cr```. Still this menu item remains visible no matter the permissions, and I'm not logged in as admin.

Comment: This is almost exactly the same I'm doing, I just don't have that `expanded: true` key in my files, don't know that key. I also have an additional `options: _admin_route: TRUE` in my `routing.yml` files, because I only need that for pages with admin theme.

Answer (score 0):

Works now. Thanks Hudri for pointing me in the right direction. I re-checked your suggestion about clearing the cache. In the process I discovered that the following line was commented out in my `lazyBuilder()` method (these menu items are in my toolbar and are generated in code)

```
$manipulators = [
  ['callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess']
]
```

The absence of those lines were causing my menu to ignore access checks, apparently. Uncommenting them out solved the problem. Thanks.